# Grails unable to find pdf resources when deploying war

Tags: file, grails, web-applications, path

I'm writing an action in controller to download pdf from webapp directory. when I run the app using run-app command, it works perfectly fine. But when I create a war, it throws error of File not found on browser. My code is as below.

```
 def pdfDownlod ={
      def pdfFileName=params.pdfFileName
      def pdfFile = new File('web-app/sales/resources/pdf/'+pdfFileName)
      response.setContentType("application/pdf")
      response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=${pdfFileName}")
      response.outputStream << pdfFile?.getBytes()
      response.outputStream.flush()
      return
  }
```

Please let me know the root cause of the problem and solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this syntax , it will work fine for you.

```
def pdfFile = new File(ServletContextHolder.servletContext.getRealPath('sales/resources/pdf/'+pdfFileName))
```

Enjoy.

Comment: thanks for the answer friend. Can you tell me why my code is not working?

Comment: When we create war file then all folder of web-app directly put in your foo folder, where name of your war file is foo.war.
Is my solution working for you?

Answer (score 1):

That's because in your deployed war the web-app folder don't exists. To properly get resources in both dev and prod use the [grailsResourceLocator](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.br/2013/09/grails-goodness-accessing-resources.html) bean.

Example:

```
class MyController {

def grailsResourceLocator

  def pdfDownlod ={
      def pdfFileName = params.pdfFileName
      final Resource pdfFile = grailsResourceLocator.findResourceForURI('web-app/sales/resources/pdf/'+pdfFileName)

      response.setContentType("application/pdf")
      response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=${pdfFileName}")
      response.outputStream << pdfFile?.file.bytes // << already flushes!
      return
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. if in war, wep-app doesn't exist then from where it gets all the images,css and js?